# Is there a java library for computing 2D Voronoi diagrams for sets of line segments?

Tags: java, algorithm, computational-geometry, voronoi

Computing Voronoi diagrams for collection of line segments is often considered to be one of the most studied problems in computer science, and has lots of practical applications.

Yet I was unable to find any implementation for it in java libraries ([this](https://github.com/aewallin/openvoronoi) the best library I found, and it is written in C++). [JTS](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html), one of the best geometry APIs in java, only includes algorithm to compute Voronoi diagram from set of points.

Currently I'm reading up articles about several algorithms computing this diagram, and if everything else fails, I'll try to implement one of those myself - but I would be a lot happier if it was possible to reuse some code that was already written and tested.

Maybe there is some library for computing Voronoi diagrams for set of line segments, that I overlooked in my search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [Java applet by Takashi Ohyama](http://www.nirarebakun.com/voro/esegvoro.html) for computing the line-segment Voronoi diagram. That page also has links to resources for several related problems. The source for the applet is [here](http://www.nirarebakun.com/voro/segvoro.java).

Comment: This is the worst "Java" code I've ever seen. I can't even call it "Java", it's just another language "casted" to Java (no local variables, no booleans, no Point objects, array indexes as if they were starting at 1, Java naming conventions broken, useless methods obfuscating the real ones like Math.pow/random/sqrt...). I wouldn't have written this comment just for that ; I warn that we don't know how it was tested, and I can say that the case of 2 points producing a vertical edge/segment was not considered (it's buggy).

Comment: @syme - I'm not surprised it's buggy. As to the Java quality, note that the code is probably close to a decade old, if not older.